# get result of intent without OnActivityResult

Tags: android, android-intent

I need to get the path of the result image path from intent without using the onActivityResult.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

I need the path of the image to the next step in OnCreate which is after the this intent started. Is there any way to get this done without using OnActivityResult ??

Comment: Do you want to perform Activity layout changes after the Intent? I mean, that's what you need the path for, right?

Comment: I need the result image path to pass it to a new method and start a new intent. this intent can be only created inside the onCreate due to my application structure

Comment: Without code samples, I can only suggest you to re-think your Activity structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need the path of the image to the next step in OnCreate which is after the this intent started

That is not possible. `startActivityForResult()` does not even begin doing its work until after your current callback (`onCreate()`, apparently) returns.

> Is there any way to get this done without using OnActivityResult ?

No.

> I need the result image path to pass it to a new method and start a new intent.

Do that in `onActivityResult()`.

> this intent can be only created inside the onCreate due to my application structure

That seems unlikely. Even if for some bizarre reason it is true, create the base `Intent` in `onCreate()`, store it in a field of your activity, and use the `Intent` in `onActivityResult()`.